# I have an answer that applies to two related questions

Tags: discussion

I have an answer that is suitable to two separate related questions. Both questions have different nuances. But my answer relates, and in my opinion is useful for both of them. Can I post the same answer in both threads?

Specifically, Here are the questions:

[Creating hard and soft links using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894430/creating-hard-and-soft-links-using-powershell/49944173#49944173)

[How to create permanent PowerShell Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases)

Comment: If the questions have different nuances, shouldn't your answer address those?

Comment: Moderators automaticlally get a warning about that, they usually delete it with a stern warning.  You'll get a pass when you customize each answer to fit the specific question.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: *it's actually an auto comment that we use if we detect similar answer from same OP by using these darn bots* Hans will not be happy :), but it will give you an idea what will happen if you do.

Comment: If you got a question "_How to make it hard?_", another one "_How to make it soft?_", and your answer addresses both hard and soft, then yes, it's fine to post it twice.

Comment: @Ben: Are you sure that your answer really answers this questions? From reading it, I have the feeling that `New-Alias` only affects the powershell session but not other processes. At least the first question (where your answer is), asks to create a file-system link (similar to Linux hard/soft links).

Comment: @BDL Thanks for your insight. I guess symbolic  link and hard link should be in the operating system level, and apply to all shells, not just powershell. On the other hand "A permanent Alias" is  a different story and refers to the specific shell. I'll go over the  terms and update my answer accordingly in the coming days.